# Replacing text with table of contents in word from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace, ms-word, find, tableofcontents

In my word template I have a text field where I need to insert Table of Content. 
CONTENTS:
[TOC]

I need to find [TOC] and replace it with Table of content. So far I've got this code:

```
     With oDoc
            .TablesOfContents.Add(Range:=oApp.Selection.Range, _
                       RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
                       UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
                       IncludePageNumbers:=True, _
                       AddedStyles:="styleSection", _
                       UseHyperlinks:=False, _
                       HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, _
                       UseOutlineLevels:=True)
            .TablesOfContents(1).Range.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
            .TablesOfContents(1).Range.Font.Size = 11
            .TablesOfContents(1).TabLeader = Word.WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots
            .TablesOfContents.Format = Word.WdTocFormat.wdTOCSimple
        End With
```

But the problem is that, it always puts the table of content on top of the document instead of finding the specific text and replacing it. Any help regarding finding specific text and replacing it with table of content would be really appreciated.

Comment: Prep: Under File Options  choose the View Tab and check the  Field Codes  option so that you can see the Field codes - you may find this very enlightening as to what is going on when dealing with TOC.       Place the cursor where you want the insert to take place First.   There may be and option to use the Inset Field of TOC type as well.  Just an FYI.

Comment: Under File Options  choose the Advanced Tab and check the show Field Codes  option so that you can see the Field codes - you may find this very enlightening